# Is there a way to filter the protocols allows in a href

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using ckeditor 4.5 and we've recently added the OWASP Html Sanitizer in the back end to screen for XSS attacks. One of the the features of that tool is a filter on what protocols are allowed on href elements.

What we've found is that even though our protocol list matches the one from the link people keep pasting content into ckeditor with different protocols that we do not support e.g.  which we would like to filter out from within ckeditor so we don't flag a naive cut&paste as an xss attack.

It seems like the AdvancedContentFilter is able to specify individual classes and styles, but not href protocols or more general attribute values.

Is it possible to do this from within CKEDITOR?

Edit:
Getting closer I think, I added:

```
config.disallowedContent = {
    a: {
        match: function(element) {
            var allowedProtcols = /^(?:http|https|mailto|tel|ftp|news):/;
            return !allowedProtcols.test(element.attributes.href);
        }
    }
};
```

Unfortunately that seems to make the link button disappear from the menu bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is a combination of the match function and special casing cke-test.

```
config.allowedContent = {
    'a': {
        match: function(element) {
            if (element.attributes.href === 'cke-test' ) { return true; }
            var allowedProtcols = /^(?:http|https|mailto|tel|ftp|news):/;
            return allowedProtcols.test(element.attributes.href);
        },
        attributes: '!href'
    },
...
};
```